# R function scope and parallelism

Tags: r, function, parallel-processing, scope

Consider the following function definitions

```
library(doParallel)
f_print <- function(x)
{
  print(x)
}
f_foreach <- function(l)
{
  foreach (i=l) %do%
  {
    f_print(i)
  }
}

f_foreach_parallel <- function(l)
{
  doParallel::registerDoParallel(1)
  foreach (i=l) %dopar%
  {
    f_print(i)
  }
}
```

Function use :

```
> f_foreach(c(1,2))
[1] 1
[1] 2
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 2

> f_foreach_parallel(c(1,2))
 Show Traceback

 Rerun with Debug
 Error in { : 
  task 1 failed - "impossible de trouver la fonction "f_print"" 
  [Error: could not find function f_print]
>
```

Can you help explain why the `f_print()` is not visible when parallelism is involved in `foreach` ? How can we use `f_print()` in this paralleled `foreach` ?Any documentations related to this point ?

Comment: The second function works for me without error. I'm running the latest of each package (doParallel 1.0.11 and foreach 1.4.3) on R 3.4.2.

Comment: That's baffling. I was using doParallel_1.0.10 and foreach_1.4.3. I just  updated to the same latest version as yours and the problem is still there. Any thoughts ?

Comment: That is strange. I just re-ran the code with a fresh version of R and did not get an error. Are you working in Windows? If so, there is some possibility that you'll have to export the function like this: `foreach (i=l, .export=c("f_print")) %dopar%`. If this works, then the issue has to do with the difference between `snow` and `mcapply` where the first works on all OS's and the second only works in *nix's. I am running openSuse linux.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [could not find function inside foreach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4765256/could-not-find-function-inside-foreach-loop)

Comment: You hit the spot. I use Windows and indeed _export_ solves it. That's some twist there. Also, `foreach` with parallel does not return list as normal `foreach`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what has already been said in the comments of the top post, especially the one on specifying `.export`, when using the [doFuture](https://cran.r-project.org/package=doFuture) package your code will indeed work regardless of parallel backend, operating system, and `.export`.  Here's an adapted version of your setup:

```
f_print <- function(x) {
  print(x)
}

f_foreach <- function(l) {
  foreach(i=l) %do% {
    f_print(i)
  }
}

f_foreach_dopar <- function(l) {
  foreach(i=l) %dopar% {
    f_print(i)
  }
}
```

Instead of doing:

```
library("doParallel")

## Setup PSOCK workers (just as on Windows)
workers <- parallel::makeCluster(1L, outfile = "")
registerDoParallel(workers)

f_foreach_dopar(c(1,2))
## Error in { : task 1 failed - "could not find function "f_print""
```

you can do:

```
library("doFuture")
registerDoFuture()

## As above
workers <- parallel::makeCluster(1L, outfile = "")
plan(cluster, workers = workers)

f_foreach_dopar(c(1,2))
## [1] 1
## [1] 2
## [[1]]
## [1] 1
## 
## [[2]]
## [1] 2
```

The reason why this works is that doFuture does a more thorough search to identify global variables (here `f_print()`).

PS. The reason for `outfile = ""` is so that stdout/stderr output (e.g. as from `print()`) is actually displayed.  Redirecting stdout/stderr in parallel processing, which I don't recommend, is a whole different discussion, but I'll assume you used `print()` just for your example.